# Django's TestCase doesn't seem to clean up database between tests

Tags: python, django, testing

I have written a test to check the integrity of the data I keep in my fixtures. It is a class inheriting from `django.tests.TestCase`, and it declares the fixtures it needs. When I run the methods in this class only, they pass. However, when I run all of my tests, some fixtures from other tests remain in the db, which makes the tests fail. I tried different variants, and for now I am overriding the `setUpTestData` class method to kill all db data before my test, but this can't be right. There must be a better way :)

```
class FixturesTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ["tariff.json"]

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        TariffModel.objects.all().delete()

    def test_tariff_fixtures(self):
        """Check the fixtures for tariffs"""
        ...
```

Thanks.

**UPD:** That said, some of the other tests do load their own fixtures. But I thought they should be dropped between tests.

Comment: Can you post a small code example to reproduce the error? Also, what specific Django version are you using (`1.x.xx`)?

Comment: I upgraded to 1.11.5, but it didn't help.

Comment: Same problem, but only with postgresql. With sqlite3 it does clear the db as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) by invoking `call_command` in `setUp`, like this you don't have to do any `Cleanup`

```
from django.core.management import call_command

class FixturesTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Load fixtures
        call_command('loaddata', 'path/to/tariff.json')
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue which is 2 days late. good news for us, there are several solutions,

Solution 1

Make sure if you are overriding the class method tearDownClass that you call `super().tearDownClass()`. If you override `tearDownClass()` without calling its super, it will in turn never call `TransactionTestCase._post_teardown()` nor `TransactionTestCase._fixture_teardown()`. Quoting from the doc string in `TransactionTestCase._post_teardown()`:

```
    def _post_teardown(self):
        """
        Perform post-test things:
        * Flush the contents of the database to leave a clean slate. If the
          class has an 'available_apps' attribute, don't fire post_migrate.
        * Force-close the connection so the next test gets a clean cursor.
        """
```

If `TestCase.tearDownClass()` is not called via `super()` then the database is not reset in between test cases and you will get the dreaded duplicate key exception.

Solution 2

Override TransactionTestCase and set the class variable serialized_rollback = True, like this:

```
class MyTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    fixtures = ['test-data.json']
    serialized_rollback = True

    def test_name_goes_here(self):
        pass
```

Quoting from the source:

```
class TransactionTestCase(SimpleTestCase):

    ...

    # If transactions aren't available, Django will serialize the database
    # contents into a fixture during setup and flush and reload them
    # during teardown (as flush does not restore data from migrations).
    # This can be slow; this flag allows enabling on a per-case basis.
    serialized_rollback = False
```

When serialized_rollback is set to True, Django test runner rolls back any transactions inserted into the database between test cases. And batta bing, batta bang... no more duplicate key errors!

you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776790/django-tests-setuptestdata-on-postgres-throws-duplicate-key-value-violates-un), for more details